# How to use same container for different stages in gitlab pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have three different stages, each should be running in a same container as there are many customizations and installations which can't be processed or mapped to a new container.

1. install the application and run the main logic(deploy command).
2. Undeploy command.
3. Clean up

If Stage 1 fails/success, then Stage 2 should still execute.
And If Stage1/Stage2 fails then only stage 3 should execute.

As there is no option to use same container for three different stages, I thought to club all of them in a single stage also. But once the stage 1 portion failed, it is not proceeding to next steps.

If I keep `allow_failure: true`, even with necessary portion also, it is not failing.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, jobs and stages don't normally share the same container.

One workaround for that is to put all your steps and logic in a script file (PowerShell, bash, etc...) and just run it in one job, not making full use of gitlab CI but will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Gitlab Container registry for this case (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/)

I use for tagging the gitlab container registry and it creates a container which gets loaded up each time.

I figured this out by running into problems and now I am going to use it for my needs.

The Pipeline configuration looks like this for my release job.

```
release_job:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
```

In this release job a tag gets checkout out by git and I create a release branch out of it and add this to a release in gitlab itself.
I ran in to problems when I wanted to delete the release including the branch and rerun the job, cause on the local git repository of my docker container the release branch already existed and did lead to an error.

So you can use the container registry for your needs. It is also possible to setup your own container registry in your current gitlab instance, but I am currently not aware if you need a none free license or similar.